# Why my C# does not have System.ServiceProcess Library?

Tags: c#, .net, service, assembly-references

This is the code. I just wanna test the library of System.ServiceProcess library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
            var srv = new ServiceController("MyService");
            Console.WriteLine("MyService Status {0}", srv.Status);
            if (srv.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                srv.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the C# code, its says:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ServiceProcess' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What went wrong?

Comment: `Are you missing an assembly reference?` The error is guiding you toward the solution already. Look up [`ServiceController `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) and you'll see this: `Assembly:  System.ServiceProcess (in System.ServiceProcess.dll)`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [`System.ServiceProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace belongs to `System.ServiceProcess.dll` and it isn't added as a reference by default.

For this, in the solution window, right click on "References" and choose "Add Reference..".  Go to the .NET tab, and double click on *System.ServiceProcess.dll*.

[image]

This assembly is probably in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`.

Answer (score 10):

Install the NuGet Package System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

Comment: Confirmed for .Net 6.0 and above

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a reference to the corresponding .dll as well.

Right click on the project -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework -> System.ServiceProcess

Answer (score 3):

you should add this from framework list
Right click on the project -> Add Reference -> search under "Assemblies" -> select->OK

[image]